# Getting unfiltered text into a textbox

Tags: vb.net, validation

I'm receiving labels from a Zebra barcode scanner and part of each scan string includes the characters h04 (EOT), h1D ("GS" character), and h1E ("RS" character).

I want the scanner input to go directly into a textbox, or some other object in VB without stripping out control characters. Then I can parse out the string to retrieve the data in the scan string.

The problem in a nutshell is that VB is stripping out some of the control characters.

I've tried the control.Validating event, but the characters that I need are still being stripped out.

For example, "sstr" when viewed in the watch panel

> ""[)>" & ChrW(30) & "06P126948676JUN1369450811015364920LE14A00521LKH
>   447K3B8J001DQ57Q120GT7Q40PL7Q8PK2SB" & ChrW(30)"

The string as it appears in textbox3:

> "[)>06P126948676JUN1369450811015364920LE14A00521LKH
>   447K3B8J001DQ57Q120GT7Q40PL7Q8PK2SB"

In Notepad++ it's:

> "[)>06P126948676JUN1369450811015364920LE14A00521LKH
>   447K3B8J001DQ57Q120GT7Q40PL7Q8PK2SB"

And while the Notepad++ string may not show up here correctly, the scanner inputs it into the editor without stripping any characters.

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.Validating
    Dim sstr As String
    sstr = TextBox3.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not that they are being stripped out because, if they were, you wouldn't see them in `sstr`. The issue is that they cannot be displayed by the control. If you copy from the UI then you'll only get what is displayed. You need to copy the text programmatically.

Comment: I'd suggest looping through the string and checking for ascii codes that are below 32 and replacing those with a string that includes "chrw" for example if a character has the code 13, then replace that character with a string such as "chrw(13)" or "<cr>" etc. After that has been done, assign the string to the TextBox.Text property

Comment: Well, not all of them are being stripped out, just some of the ones that I need. :) I modified the code to use the scanner on the serial port, which allows me full control of my data stream. In that aspect, the problem is solved. But it would be nice to have a text control that allows more control. And thanks for your help!